# How to prove that a metric is Einstein?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

A manifold is called as Einstein if

$$R_{ab} = kg_{ab}$$

For example $a,b=1,...,3$ and

$$R_{11} = k g_{11} $$

$$R_{22} = k g_{22} $$

$$R_{33} = k g_{33} $$

**My question is:**

1. Does the constant $k$ here have the same value for $R_{11}, R_{22}$ and $R_{33}$ ?
2. If I get the different values of $k$ for each Ricci tensors, then is it correct to say that the metric is not Einstein?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.